# Why is C++ unnecessary loop making program faster?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization

I was practicing on some competitive programming site, like [UVa](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/) or [LOj](http://lightoj.com/index.php) and noticed several times(10 times or more!) that putting an unnecessary loop in my program, for example, putting this at the beginning of the program-

```
for (int _delay = 0; _delay < 500000000; _delay++ );
```

makes it run faster(!) that usual and gives me better ranks. I've resubmitted over and over again, but this keeps on happening.
My question is how is this possible? Just a coincidence(which happened lots of times) or is the compiled program getting optimized for some reason?

Comment: In case you are wondering, I wrote a delay function once and I called it at the beginning of my program by mistake the first time this had happened.

Comment: You can settle most questions about optimization by comparing the machine code with and without that loop.

Comment: Ok that's a bit odd, but I could see that changing the value of some heuristics and that could ultimately make the compiler compile it differently. Look at the assembly code to find out.

Comment: Btw, if the time interval between your first and the second submission to UVa is long (e.g., more than one year), keep in mind that UVa keeps upgrading their systems so your second try will definitely run faster than your first try even the code is the same.

Comment: @keelar I've resubmitted those codes with and without the for loop within minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming such a useless loop has any effect on the compiled code, one source of performance difference could be branch instructions falling in different buckets, making branch prediction in the CPU more accurate (see [Why would introducing useless MOV instructions speed up a tight loop in x86_64 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896714/why-would-introducing-useless-mov-instructions-speed-up-a-tight-loop-in-x86-64-a)). You would have to run the program in a controlled environment for proper testing though; I wouldn't trust the measurements made by an online judge.

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the compilers will ignore the following statement you mentioned:

```
for (int _delay = 0; _delay < 500000000; _delay++ );
```

since the for-loop does nothing but merely modifying a local variable which scope only lies in the for-loop.

As for the above statement makes the WHOLE program faster ... I don't think it could ...

Comment: Is there a possibility that the compiler is ignoring this code segment and trigger an optimization while compiling?

Comment: There might be such possibility, but I don't think this could apply to  the general case though ....

Comment: Yes, this is completely strange. I've checked the case for several other solutions of mine since posting this question. That timing distinction just persists!

Comment: @user1362452: How big is this distinction? Is it statistically significant? Can you give an assembly listing with and without?

Comment: Then the only way is to try to get the compiler used by UVa and compare their binaries ...

Comment: @GManNickG: Adding the for loops are giving around 20-30% better run-time

Comment: When you observe 20-30% better run-time, can I know the actual absolute run-time? Just want to know how many perc could be bias.

Comment: @keelar:  http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3639
this problem, with loop 6 MS, without 9 MS.

This one-http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2101,
with loop 102 MS, without 124 MS

Comment: Most optimizers (and some frontends) would throw that loop away as dead code since nothing is done with any byproduct of the loop.  Even calling `printf( "%d", _delay )` outside of the loop with _delay as an argument wouldn't necessarily save it.  Some compilers are smart enough to eliminate the loop and just `printf( "500000000" );`